# searching vector [ error included version  & orginal code & Makefile  ]

Tags: c++

- It gives so many error, why ?
- How can I fix it ?

My real code ;

```
 int  SearchUserName (  string searched,   vector<User *> list  )   {
 vector<User *> :: iterator it ;
 for ( it = list.begin() ; it < list.end ( ) ; ++it ) {
    const  string tmp = (*it) -> getUsername() ;
    if ( tmp  == searched ) return 1 ;
 }     
return 0 ;
}
  // SocialNet :: createUser
  void SocialNet :: createUser (const string username, const string name, \
                          const string surname)   throw ( SocialNetException ) {
  int tmp = SearchUserName ( username, this -> users ) ;
  if(  tmp  == 0) {
     User *tmp = NULL ;
     tmp = new User( username, name, surname ) ;
     users.push_back ( tmp ) ;     
       return ;
 }
 throw  SocialNetException (USER_ALREADY_EXISTS, username)  ; 
}
```

Finally, I have find, Error:

(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/cckzaRBZ.o: In function`SearchUserName(std::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::vector >)':
SocialNet.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `User::getUsername() const'
/tmp/cckzaRBZ.o: In function`SocialNet::createUser(std::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator >)':
SocialNet.cpp:(.text+0x258): undefined reference to `User::User(std::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator >)'

EDIT: 
in makefile ;

```
 CXX = g++
 CXXFLAGS_W = -Werror -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wunused-function \
         -Wfloat-equal -Wall
 CXXFLAGS_M = -ansi  -pedantic-errors
 CXXFLAGS = ${CXXFLAGS_M} ${CXFLAGS_W}

 all:    main
        ./main
```

compile ; make filename

Comment: You'll have better luck getting help if you post the errors.

Comment: We don't know. We might know if you post those errors.

Comment: I wish to send error, but few minutes ago, really, my flash disk has closed itself, and erased all of the data I have in it. So, I couldnot  ... ( I think lab computer found some virus and then erased all data in my flash disk )

Comment: Some error messages would be helpful. But the condition it < listOfPeople.end() should be written as it != listOfPeople.end()

Comment: You should probably pass your vector by const-reference and use const_iterators. Passing by reference will avoid copying the whole set of pointers.

Comment: @Kai: No. For vectors it is correct. What you suggest is only good practice, not what is wrong here.

Comment: Is this actually your real code?  You use both `ClassName` and `className`.

Comment: please post your complete sourcecode and errors

Comment: What errors? What is the class definition? Your annotation is useless as there is obviously an error in your translation from English to C++.

Comment: @eznme: A testcase would be preferable to his entire codebase.

Comment: @Benoit: Disagree. Iterators are a generic concept; you should not be handling them differently just because you're using a vector or a list etc. Always write `it != v.end()`. (And, yes, I know that this principle gets ruined when you come to erase-iteration idioms that are different across containers. Sad exception case.)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I said it is good practice to write `!=` so we agree. I have never said that `<` is the right way, just that in this case it is correct.

Comment: @all people, finally I rescued my flash disk. If you look new version you will see error

Comment: How are you invoking the compiler?

Comment: but this is a linker error? So the error is obviously not in the code you posted

Comment: why is it shows "functionSearchUserName .... " as error ?

Comment: because SearchUserName calls User::getUsername() which seems to be missing

Comment: @Benoit: Ok. Perhaps "valid" would be a better word than "correct", then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only compiling one file.

something like

```
main: foo.o bar.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ foo.o bar.o
```

listing all your object files

Answer (score 0):

Comment all your code. And uncomment line after line to  determine which line causing the problem.

Comment: @Doug: To solve the problem you have first to find the problem

Comment: @Kai: to use debugger your program must compile first

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling lucky.

```
class people
{
public: // <--- add this line

    string getpersonname();

};
```

Comment: I propose that we all give out something that could cause an error. Your solution is: some method might be nonpublic. This is going to be the most answered question on SO. Mine is `using namespace std` forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I think your linker errors are being caused by the fact that one of your .cpp files is not being compiled into the program.